# Python - create gif from numerically-labeled individual frames

Tags: python, file, sorting, alphanumeric

I have a directory that contains PNGs named `frame1.png`, `frame2.png`, and so on. I want to create a GIF using these PNGs as frames, in the order However my code creates a GIF using `frame1.png` as the first frame and `frame10.png` as the second frame. This is probably due to my code reading every PNG in the directory and combining each frame all at once. How do I generate a GIF using `frame1.png` as the first frame and `frame2.png` as the second frame, and so on?

My code is:

```
import glob
from PIL import Image
def make_gif(frame_folder):
    frames = [Image.open(image) for image in glob.glob(f"{frame_folder}/*.png")]
    frame_one = frames[0]
    frame_one.save("gif_name.gif", format="GIF", append_images=frames,
               save_all=True, duration=100, loop=0)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    make_gif("path_to_directory")
```

Specifically, how do I ensure that `glob` sorts the files the way I want? Should I use another package?

I have tried sorting the files with the `os` package but couldn't figure out what to do next.

Comment: You could make a list of the image file *names*, which you could then sort any way you wanted.  From that list of names you could make your list of images.

Comment: This would have been a much easier problem to solve if you had created your individual frame files with leading zeros on the numeric part, so that they were all the same length.  That way, a simple alphabetic sort would be the same thing as the desired numeric sort.

Comment: @jasonharper I did end up doing that (for anyone looking at this question in the future the relevant solution is ``str(i).zfill(2)``) but glob() still sorts incorrectly.